# Action of right angled Coveter group on its Davis complex

Tags: geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

For any right-angled Coxeter group $W_{\Gamma}$, we denote the Davis complex by $\Sigma_{\Gamma}$.

I wonder how to see $W_{\Gamma}$ acts on this complex (by left multiplication) with finite stabilisers?
Moreover why thus, any torsion-free subgroup of finite index acts freely on $\Sigma_{\Gamma}$?

Comment: Have you looked in Davis' book? https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/my%20book/My%20book.html

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks